# multiple javascript window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that I am using in html for a popup user form.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('basemodal');

var btn = document.getElementById("basebutton");

var span = document.getElementById("close1");

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I am using this script in multiple places within the html document.

The only thing that I can't get to work properly is the `window.onclick`.

Since there are various script statements with this `window.onclick`, this only works for the **last** popup user form. What this does is when someone clicks on the screen it closes the popup box.

Is there a way to have multiple window statements? I tried setting for instance, `window1 = window;` and `window2 = window`; with no luck.

Thank you in advance!

Possible solution with eventlistener?? I tried but no luck:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event)){
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only ever one `window`.  It sounds like you want `addEventListener`.

Comment: @SLaks something like this?

window.addEventListener("click", function(event)){
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

Comment: _I am using this script in multiple places within the html document_ : really? So you don't recognize that using global variables with exactly the same identifier will overwrite each other _"in multiple places within the html document"_? It is closing the last modal because that is the last element to overwrite the modal variable.

Comment: @RandyCasburn sorry, I changed each of the variable names, I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with some code this is the best solution:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```